# Legend units for geom_point size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have used geom_point in ggplot2 to display values as the area of each point:

```
geom_point(aes(size = sqrt(z/pi))
```

However, the legend units are the transformed values, is it possible to have the legend display the original values alongside their respective bubble size?

Edit: sorry I should have provided more information to begin with

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(x = sample(1:10), y = sample(1:10), z = sample(1:10), colour = c("red", "yellow", "green","pink","black","brown","grey","white","purple","beige"))

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(aes(size = sqrt(z/pi)), pch = 21) + aes(fill = colour) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "set1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
+scale_colour_manual(guide = guide_legend(override.aes=aes(size=values)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is on the right path.  One problem is that I already have an existing legend for colours. but I currently receive an 'Error in scale$palette(n) : argument "values" is missing, with no default'